# Trouble deploying Activiti-app.war form Activiti 6 on Tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, activiti

I'm trying to deploy Activiti-app.war and activiti-rest.war from Activiti 6 onto my Tomcat Server.
I configured the property files like this (based on the information provided in the activiti userguide):

```
    # DATABASE
#

datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti

#datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/activiti6ui?
characterEncoding=UTF-8

datasource.username=postgres
datasource.password=postgres

#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Full File here: [Pastebin .properties File.](https://pastebin.com/btBJdEtq)

And even if I use the unmodified .war file activiti website provides, I always get these errors: [Pastebin Tomcat Log](https://pastebin.com/F5F58GJn)

I would be very grateful for help. Thanks.

Comment: Problem is with your tomcat i guess, do you have something already running on the PORT you have assigned on your tomcat?

Comment: I checked that, seems not to be the problem. For further Information and clarification, a few Screenshots. 
Ports in Terminal before and after starting Tomcat :
 " https://imageshack.com/i/pm0RIKiwp " .
Error Message in Tomcat UI: " https://imageshack.com/i/pocdsj1yp " .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it.
The Problem was, I was using JDK 9, apparently Activiti 6 doesnt yet go together with JDK 9, so changing back to JDK 8 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Abbas indicated, it's obvious you already have an application listening on that port:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:225)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:227)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:202)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1039)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:540)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:932)
    ... 13 more
```

Change the Tomcat to use an unbound port and it will likely startup just fine.

Comment: @KSGPhellow how do you check if your tomcat is running properly? can you please hit <yourHost>:<yourPort> on your local system and share your result?

Comment: Like this? https://imageshack.com/i/poSf04u6p .                                               
If it helps, I cleared my logs and started Tomcat again to see if anything is clearer.                                                                                                                
localhost.log: https://pastebin.com/KGMACX9M , and 
catalina.log: https://pastebin.com/ktruKRY4                                                         
I'm currently at a loss Oo

Answer (score 0):

change your properties code like this:

```
db=<your database name>
datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/<your database name>?characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false

datasource.username=root
datasource.password=<database connection password>

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.